# Is it possible to get the old dark Firefox developer console back?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-developer-tools

The Firefox console used to be dark themed like [this](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/6411/debugger-black-box-fx26.png).

Now it is white. Any idea how to get the old console back? I have Classic Theme Restorer, but couldn't find it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dark theme you are referring is still there as I see it now.

Go to your FF browser and click: **Tools** / **Web Developer** / **Web console**

On the left hand side, you will find a button named **Toolbox Options**. whenever you click on it, you will see the theme style chooser. You can choose Dark Theme and it will be changed directly the same as the old one.